# Match number in python using re

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, complex-numbers

I got many data wrote in this form(read from file):

```
(31265+0j)
(-5613.54281374+404.957401125j)
(1371.65134844+2671.06617046j)
...
```

And yet I want to extract the numerical part, like `[31265, 0]` or `[-5613.54281374 , 404.957401125]` , I coded in python in the way I thought it would work:

```
re.findall(r'.*([\+|\-]?\d+.?\d+)([\+|\-]?\d+.?\d+).*', tempStr)
```

But it does not work, it gave me this:

```
[]
[('26', '5+0')]
[('11', '25')]
...
```

What's wrong with it? Is it something about lazy mode? And how should I fix it?

========================Update========================
For me, this question is solved, but I still wonder what's wrong with the regular expression part, is there someone willing to help me point out what's wrong with the regex pattern?

Comment: Both are numerical parts!! What you have here are complex numbers. the j stands for sqrt(-1)

Comment: See [**`ast.literal_eval`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: Still want to use regex? Ok, see my updated answer then :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are numbers. You should not use regex here. The first part is the `real` and the second part is the `imaginary` you can access them like this

```
 n = (-5613.54281374+404.957401125j)
 n.real
 n.imag
```

This maybe hard to spot at first because in maths we often use `i = sqrt(-1)` but in python it's `j = sqrt(-1)` But quit interestingly, if you do

```
import math
math.sqrt(-1)
```

you will get a `ValueError`

**Update**:

If the data is in a file

```
with open('complex.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        number = complex(line.strip())
```

**Update 2:**
if you really, really, really want to use regex:

```
 map(float, line[1:-2].split('+'))
```

Use re.split() instead if you have numbers where the complex part can be negative.

Comment: You can do `cmath.sqrt(-1)`

Comment: Well, I do know about complex number, but these are read from file(Sorry didn't mention that at first), so I don't know how to deal with it... I tried `eval()` after your advice, but I got a `unexpected EOF while parsing` ...

Comment: Sorry but I got that: `complex() arg is a malformed string` ... What's wrong with it...

Comment: Yep, fixed after deal with the space, thank you soooo much!

Comment: Glad to have been of help. All the best with your project.

Answer (score 1):

Using .real and .imag will give you the output you desire

```
   foo = (31265 + 0j)
   bar = [foo.real , bar.imag]
   #>>>[31265.0 , 0.0]
```